# Zuul: How to get path variables from request

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

Using Zuul, how do I extract the path variables (`customerId` and `agreementId`) given the following URL:

> customers/{`customerId`}/agreements/{`agreementId`}

Can I somehow get the reference names for the path variables using Zuul or Eureka or do I need to use RegEx or something similar?

Comment: zuul is used for proxy. so you should navigate request to a restcontroller. and customerid etc. should not be logical property for routing. So you should parse path variables at controller.

Comment: Yes, we are of course parsing the path variables at controller-level. But I would like to validate the customerId and agreementId in the Zuul gateway service before passing the request to the API.

Comment: So, u can implement your `javax.servlet.Filter` at gateway service and make some logic with incoming request at `doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) { ... }` method

Comment: https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-cloud/configure-springboot-zuul-routing-filtering

Comment: I know how to implement custom filters with Zuul but I want to access the path variables by referencing them. The link just has a generic guide to creating filters but does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx is definitely one of the option to explore

Comment: I would much rather be able to reference the path variables by name, so for me RegEx is not the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter which will be used before your request actually goes to the controller.

You can extract path variables from HttpServletRequest like this:

```
Map<String, String> pathVariables = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
```

Comment: That returns null in my case.
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();  
  Map<String, String> pathVariables = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);

  System.out.println(pathVariables);

Comment: I am getting null as well. Did you find a solution?

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I also have such a demand recently, I am studying how to solve this problem, you can refer to the `AntPathMatcher` class in `Spring Core`, maybe it will help you